# Critical damping: second solution of oscillator differential equation with pertubation

Tags: oscillators

With critical damping, when you look at the characteristic polynomial you have a double root instead of two distinct roots, but there must nonetheless be two separate solutions to the differential equations. The argument my professor used to get the second solution was the following:

$e^{-\gamma t}$ is certainly a solution, now observe the functions

$x_{1}(t)=e^{(-\gamma+\epsilon) t}=e^{-\gamma t}e^{-\epsilon t}=e^{-\gamma t}(1-t\epsilon+...)$

$x_{2}(t)=e^{(-\gamma-\epsilon) t}=e^{-\gamma t}(1+t\epsilon+...)$

Then he goes on to say

$\dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}(x_{2}-x_{1})=\dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}e^{-\gamma t}(0+2\epsilon t+...)$

for $\epsilon\to0:x_{2}(t)=te^{-\gamma t}$

I neither understand the basis of this argument, or the argument from the $x_{2}-x_{1}$ line and further. Why does perturbing the exponent give a new solution?

Comment: Explained in more detail - [Critical Damping: A Special Case](https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/Oscillations3.htm)

Comment: The link in Farcher's comment is much more sensible. However, do note that all such arguments are really just us trying random ideas to try and get something. We are protected by uniqueness and existence theorems, so if we find something, that something is definitely a correct answer. If you really want to learn about solving differential equations without all these weird random arguments to nowhere, you should consult a proper textbook on the subject. There is no avoidance of random arguments, but we can avoid them for the standard basic stuff quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to find the solutions to $$\left(\partial_t+\gamma\right)^2x=0.$$

Now we know $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the two solutions to the perturbed equation: $$\left(\partial_t+\gamma+\varepsilon\right)\left(\partial_t+\gamma-\varepsilon\right)x=0.$$

And the linear combination of the two: $(x_2-x_1)/2\varepsilon$ is also a solution to the perturbed equation. When taking the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$, since the perturbed equation converges to the original equation, the solution should also converge.

If you want to be more rigorous about everything, you'll need to look into operator theory, which in my opinion is too much details.

Note: the factor $1/2\varepsilon$ is needed, without it, $x_2-x_1$ converges to $0$, which doesn't give us a new solution.